# Radius of convergence of a complex serie

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Good evening, people.

I am trying to find the radius of convergente of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (4+(-1)^n )^n z^n$

I tried to use the theorem which states that $ r = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}|$. However, I could not solve this limit.

So I did the following:

$$ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (4+(-1)^n )^n z^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} 3^{2k+1}z^{2k+1} + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}5^{2k}z^{2k}$$

And said that the radius of convergence of the serie on the left side is the smallest radius between the two series on the right side.

Is this right? Is there an easy way to find the radius of convergence?

Thank you.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |4+(-1)^n|}$, so $R=1/5$.

Comment: Is there a name for the theorem that states what you've said? Furthermore, R=1/5 is also the answer when you what I said: "the radius of convergence of the serie on the left side is the smallest radius between the two series on the right side". Is this just a coincidence? Thank you, Matthew!

Comment: When I took functions of a complex variable this was how the radius of convergence was initially defined. Other texts refer to this as the root test. And no, no coincidence at all. If $\sum a_n z^n$ converges for $ |z|<R_a$ and $\sum b_n z^n$ converges for $ |z|<R_b$ then $\sum a_n z^n + \sum b_n z^n$ converges for $|z|<\min\{R_a,R_b\}$

Comment: @JeanWeigel I think the Frenchs call this formula the "Formule d'Hadamard."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, except that in English the word "series" is either singular or plural, i.e. one writes "This series is..." or "These series are..."

There is a theorem that asserts that power series converge **absolutely** at every point in the *interior* of their circles of convergence (but may converge conditionally at a point on the boundary; however, that is of no concern here).

If convergence is absolute, then the series can be "rearranged" without altering the sum. In particular,
$$
\sum_{n\,=\,0}^\infty t_n = \sum_{n\,\in\,A} t_n + \sum_{n\,\in\,B} t_n
$$
if $A,B$ are disjoint sets whose union is $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}.$

If both of the series on the right converge absolutely, then so does the series on the left.

If the series on the left converges absolutely, then so do the two series on the right.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that series is either singular or plural. Thank you again, Michael!